# Overlay does'nt show up when JQUERY ajax async set to false only in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, input, overlay

An input button invokes javascript on the click event.

```
<input id="ToolbarStatusSubmitHtmlInputButton" type="button" value="Submit" runat="server"  visible="True" enableviewstate="true" onclick="callfunction()"/>

The onclick 'callfunction' is as follow

callfunction: function() {
        showparentOverlay();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,.....

 showparentOverlay: function() {
        $("#parentOverlay").removeClass('hideOverlay').addClass('showOverlay');
    },
```

The Callfunction does 2 things

1) Changes to the DOM element by removing and adding class

2) Makes an Ajax Call
       It is purposefully made async false, to retrive the value from service and get confirmation from user.

The issue is only in IE browser where showparentOverlay(transparent div) does'nt show until the ajax service call is completed.

However if the AJAX async is SET true the overlay displays.

Can anyone please help me with this issue , where I could display the transparent overlay while the connection to service is made and the async for the service is set - false.

Thanks

Comment: `async:false` is bad. Don't use it. It freezes some (older) browsers while the request is loading.

Comment: @ThiefMaster is right, why use `Asynchronous Javascript And XML` if you don't want it to be `Asynchronous`

Comment: I can't confirm this behaviour on any of my installed IEs, so my first suggestion will be: clear IEs cache.

Comment: Async = true works, but to get something a confirmation from the user I want it as sync. is there any alternative solution .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the `async` option to `true` and using the `success` function to load the overlay...

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(data){
      //Show Overlay here
   }
});
```

This will call the service and upon success will then open your overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
  function oninputclick()  {
    document.getElementById("window").style.width = "100%";
        
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',                                
      success: function (result) {
        // success do something                   
      },
      complete: function () {
        // enable this when posting to server
        //setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("window").style.width = "0%"; }, 3000);
      }      
    });
    //for test only. use this inside the complete function.
    setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("window").style.width = "0%"; }, 3000);
  }
```

```css
            .overlay {
                height: 100%;
                width: 0;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 9999999;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
                overflow-x: hidden;
                transition: 0.5s;
            }

            .overlay-content {
                position: relative;
                top: 25%;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 30px;
            }           

            .overlay a {
                padding: 8px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 36px;
                color: #f1f1f1;
                display: block;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="window" class="overlay">  
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="msgText">Loading...</a>                
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Submit" runat="server"  visible="True" onclick="oninputclick();"/>
```